# Simple ways to group in Teradata

Tags: teradata

When I try to run this query it fails :

```
SELECT COUNT(id), (CURRENT_DATE - birth_dt) / 365 AS  age
FROM  players
ORDER BY age
GROUP BY    age
```

---

There are many work arounds, something like this works fine :

```
WITH ages (id, age) as 
(SELECT id, (CURRENT_DATE - birth_dt) / 365 AS  age
FROM  players ) 
SELECT COUNT(id), age
FROM  ages 
ORDER BY age
GROUP BY    age
```

**But this seems to be an overkill for such a trivial problem.** Is there any straightforward (single `select`) way ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a column in the table players that is named `AGE` as well? I can replicate your query using SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR without generating the error.

Comment: No i do not have `age` in `players`.

Comment: You can try to include `birth_dt` in your `GROUP BY` but on the surface it doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: What result do you get if you use
`Group by (CURRENT_DATE - birth_dt) / 365`
or
`Group by 2`